# Inner Join using LINQ to entities c# sql database with two related tables

Tags: linq-to-entities

Can you help please?

I have a database consisting of two tables:
TestData & Core
Table TestData has columns: ID (int) Core (int) Name(NVARCHAR) etc...
Table Core has columns: ID (int) CoreName (Nvarchar)

I have set a relationship so that the column in Testdata (testdata.Core) is linked to Core.CoreID so that i can keep all core types in one table and use numbers (int) to describe them in my main TestData table.

Im using LINQ c# and would like to show my results bound to a gridview where it shows the equivalent of an inner join so that I end up with a gridview result showing the ID and Name columns from TestData table and the CoreName from the Core Table.

So far I have this code, it seems to work but ONLY when i specify 2 conditions, eg bc.CoreID AND b.Core equal to the variable coreVar.

Now potentially I could have lots more columns and variables so i want to get this correct from the start so there must be a better way of doing this than what I have below?

Any help would be greatly appreciated....

```cs
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    coreLabel.Text = "2";
    dbLabel.Text = "5";
    widthLabel.Text = "54mm";

    int coreVar = Convert.ToInt32(coreLabel.Text);

    var gridQuery = from b in _entity.TestData
                    from bc in _entity.CoreData
                    where (bc.CoreID == (coreVar)) && (b.Core ==(coreVar))
                    select new {b.ID, bc.coreName};


    resultGrid.DataSource = gridQuery;
    resultGrid.DataBind();

}
```

Comment: Do you want to parametrize the conditions somehow?

Comment: if i understand your question, then i think yes. For the example above the labels are just populated on load but these will be passed to the results page via query string then ill use linq to query based on these parameters

Comment: OK, so with a different value you might want to do something like `bc.B == var2) && (b.B == var2)`? And maybe more `where`s?

Comment: Are these tables have relationship on ID column? if yes, why don't you use Join so you only have to specify one condition like (bc.CoreID == coreVar). Are you looking for something like that?

Comment: they do have relationship on ID column, so join may be useful, i think i may have just done a "long winded" version of a join.

Answer (score 0):

OK, it looks like you are looking for a way to expand your query dynamically.

```cs
var gridQuery = from b in _entity.TestData
                from bc in _entity.CoreData
                select new {b.ID, bc.coreName};

if (coreVar.HasValue)
{
   gridQuery = gridQuery.Where(bc.CoreID == coreVar.Value) 
                           && (b.Core == coreVar.value);
}
if (b.HasValue)
{
   gridQuery = gridQuery.Where(bc.B == b.Value) 
                           && (b.B == b.Value);
}
if ....
```

This will add `AND` conditions to your query for each defined variable, so the result will be more restricted when more conditions are defined.